# AndroidAnnotations @EBean Class Instantiation Issue

Tags: android, android-annotations

I'm implementing my own adapter class extending BaseAdapter using AA, but I need more than one parameter in the constructor to properly instantiate it. I wonder if there's any way to do it?

```
@EBean
public class MomentViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    protected LayoutInflater mInflater;
    protected Context mContext;
    protected List<FavoriteInfo> mDatas;
    protected  int mItemLayoutId;

    public MomentViewAdapter(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
//        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
//        this.mDatas = mDatas;
//        this.mItemLayoutId = itemLayoutId;
    }

    public void setUp(List<FavoriteInfo> mDatas, int itemLayoutId) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.mDatas = mDatas;
        this.mItemLayoutId = itemLayoutId;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mDatas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public FavoriteInfo getItem(int position)
    {
        return mDatas.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(mItemLayoutId, parent, false);
        }
        ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detail_moment_camera_picture);
        if (mDatas.get(position).isVideoFavorite()) {
            Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mDatas.get(position).getVideoURL(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {
            getBitmapFromURL(mDatas.get(position).getImageURL(), img);
            // img.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(mDatas.get(position).getImageURL()));
        }
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GeneratedClassUtils.get(MomentDetailActivity.class));
                Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
                mBundle.putSerializable(FavoriteInfo.KEY, mDatas.get(position));
                mBundle.putBoolean(CollectionInfo.KEY_WATCH_FLAG, false);
                intent.putExtras(mBundle);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return convertView;

    }

    @Background
    protected void getBitmapFromURL(String src, ImageView img) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            updateImageView(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input), img);
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("************** network exception: download image failed");
            return;
        }
    }

    @UiThread
    protected void updateImageView(Bitmap bitmap, ImageView img) {
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        return;
    }

}
```

Currently I'm using a setUp method to initiate the other parameters. But it seems to be problematic. I'm using it in my activity like this:

```
@EActivity
public class DeviceDetailActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Bean
    MomentViewAdapter mGridViewAdapter;

    /* some other code like @ViewById */
    @Afterviews
    public void afterViews(){
        init();
    }
    void init(){
        afterInject();
    }

    @AfterInject // injected beans are only available from here
    public void afterInject() {
        mGridViewAdapter.setUp(mMomentDatas, R.layout.device_detail_moment_listitem_simple);
        mGridView.setAdapter(mGridViewAdapter);
    }

}
```

When I ran it on my phone, I got null pointer exception:

```
unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bloomsky.bloomsky/com.bloomsky.android.activities.common.DeviceDetailActivity_}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

It appeared after setUp() method got called though, which is really confusing to me. So I think maybe the object is not instantiated correctly.

Comment: Please post the full code. The exception happens when you set the adapter to a Grid View, but the question does not contain that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mGridView` is null because `@AfterInject` is called before `@AfterViews`. Your view is simply not bound yet by Android Annotations. So use `@AfterViews` instead.